# Trouble doubling the size of array in Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, memory-management, x86-64, nasm

Trying to double the array to increase the array to add more elements. **There is no compile or runtime error but it doesn't let you input more elements after 5** I'm not sure if the array size is not doubling at all or what is happening because you can insert 5 numbers then the input will go to done and print the stats. I need it to double the array each time the user fills the array until they press (ctrl d) then it goes to output the stats.

```
   %define ARRAY_SIZE  5
   %define ELEMENT_SIZE 4
   %define EOF -1
   
segment .data
   inputPrompt: db "Enter int value (ctrl-d to stop): ",0
   intFormat:   db "%d",0
   output:      db "Array[%d] = %d",10,0
   dbout:       db 10, 10,"[%d]",10,10,0 ; This is just for debugging output
   newline:     db 10,0                  ; For whenever we need a newline
   numElements: db "Number of elements: %d",10,0
   outputSum:   db "sum of elements: %d",10,0
   minValue:    db "Min value: %d",10,0
   maxValue:    db "Max value: %d",10,0

segment .bss
   arrayPtr:  resq 1                     ; pointer to our array
   intInput:  resd 1

segment .text
   global asm_main
   extern printf, scanf, calloc, realloc
   
asm_main:
   enter 0,0

   ;; Get memory for our array
   ;; Give calloc() number of element and element size
   ;; and calloc returns a pointer to zerioized memory
   mov   rdi, ARRAY_SIZE
   mov   rsi, ELEMENT_SIZE
   call  calloc
   mov   [arrayPtr], rax
   
   mov   rdi, [arrayPtr]        ; Will use RDI and stosd to write the array
   mov   rcx, ARRAY_SIZE
   mov   r15, 0                 ; R15 counts how many elements in our array
   cld
inputLoop:
   push  rcx                    ; Save RCX and RDI across printf/scanf calls
   push  rdi
   mov   rdi, inputPrompt
   call  printf

   mov   rdi, intFormat
   mov   rsi, intInput
   call  scanf

   cmp   eax, EOF               ; Did scanf() return -1 (didn't read anything?)
   je    inputDone
  
   ; check if the array is full, if so, double its size
   cmp   r15, ARRAY_SIZE
   jl    inputNotFull
   ; double the array size and copy the elements to the new array
   mov   rsi, [arrayPtr]
   mov   rdi, ARRAY_SIZE*2*ELEMENT_SIZE
   call  realloc
   mov   [arrayPtr], rax
   mov   rcx, [ARRAY_SIZE]
   rep   movsd
   mov   eax, ARRAY_SIZE
   imul  eax, 2
   mov  [ARRAY_SIZE], eax
  
   ; continue with the input
inputNotFull:
   inc   r15                    ; O/w count another element & store it
   xor   rax, rax               ; Clear out RAX for stosd to write array to mem
   mov   eax, [intInput]
   pop   rdi                    ; Restore RDI for stosd
   stosd
   pop   rcx                    ; Restore RCS for loop instruction
   dec   rcx
   jnz   inputLoop
   
inputDone:                      ; Let's get ready to print
   mov   rdi, newline
   call  printf
   mov   rsi, [arrayPtr]        ; Will use RSI and lodsd to read the array
   mov   rcx, r15               ; Store actual array size to RCX
   mov   rbx, 0
   cld

printLoop:
   xor   rax, rax
   xor   rdx, rdx
   lodsd
   push  rcx                    ; Save RCX and RSI across printf call
   push  rsi
   mov   rdi, output
   mov   rsi, rbx

   movsx rdx, eax
   call  printf
   inc   rbx

   pop   rsi                    ; Restore RCX and RSI
   pop   rcx
   loop  printLoop
   je    printStats
   
printStats:
   mov   rdi, newline
   call  printf
   mov   rdi, numElements
   mov   rsi, r15
   call  printf
   
   mov   rax, 0         ; Initialize the sum to zero
   mov   rsi, [arrayPtr] ; Get the address of the array
   mov   rcx, r15        ; Store actual array size to RCX
   cld
   
   xor   rdx, rdx       ; Clear out RDX for the first add instruction
   
   mov   rax, 0           ; Initialize the sum to zero
   mov   rsi, [arrayPtr]  ; Get the address of the array
   mov   rcx, r15         ; Store actual array size to RCX
   cld
sumLoop:
   lodsd                  ; Load the next element of the array into EAX
   add   rax, r8          ; Add the current sum to EAX
   mov   r8, rax          ; Store the updated sum in R8
   loop  sumLoop
   mov   rdi, outputSum
   mov   rsi, r8
   call  printf
   
 ; Find the minimum value in the array
   mov   rax, [arrayPtr]     ; Load the base address of the array into RAX
   mov   ebx, [rax]          ; Load the first element of the array into EBX
   mov   rcx, r15            ; Loop counter will be the number of elements
   dec   rcx                 ; Decrement RCX since we've already loaded the first element
   mov   rsi, [rax]          ; Initialize RSI to the first element
loopStart:
   add   rax, ELEMENT_SIZE   ; Move the pointer to the next element
   cmp   [rax], ebx          ; Compare the value at the current pointer to the minimum value
   jge   loopEnd             ; If the value is greater than or equal to the minimum, skip to the end of the loop
   mov   ebx, [rax]          ; Otherwise, update the minimum value
   mov   rsi, rax            ; and store the address of the minimum value in RSI
loopEnd:
   loop  loopStart           ; Repeat for the remaining elements of the array
   mov   rdi, minValue
   mov   rsi, rbx
   call  printf

; Find the maximum value in the array
   mov   rax, [arrayPtr]     ; Load the base address of the array into RAX
   mov   ebx, [rax]          ; Load the first element of the array into EBX
   mov   rcx, r15            ; Loop counter will be the number of elements
   dec   rcx                 ; Decrement RCX since we've already loaded the first element
   mov   rsi, [rax]          ; Initialize RSI to the first element
loopStartd:
   add   rax, ELEMENT_SIZE   ; Move the pointer to the next element
   cmp   [rax], ebx          ; Compare the value at the current pointer to the maximum value
   jle   loopEndd             ; If the value is less than or equal to the maximum, skip to the end of the loop
   mov   ebx, [rax]          ; O/w, update the maximum value to the current value
   mov   rsi, rax            ; Store the address of the current maximum value
loopEndd:
   loop  loopStartd
   mov   rdi, maxValue
   mov   rsi, rbx
   call  printf

   mov   rax, 0
   leave 
   ret
```

I tried to increase rcx since that determines if it will jump back to inputLoop: to get more input but then it gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: `mov   rdi, ARRAY_SIZE*2*ELEMENT_SIZE` is a constant size, so it can only double once.  Also, `mov  [ARRAY_SIZE], eax` is a store to absolute address `5`, which will segfault.  You're sometimes using it as an address, sometimes using it like an assemble-time constant matching the way you defined it.

Answer (score 1):

> it doesn't let you input more elements after 5

That's simply because the *inputLoop* was told to do 5 iterations after which it falls through in *inputDone*.
In essence, what you need is an **endless loop** that unconditionally jumps back to the top of the *inputLoop*. Of course there will always remain the already available early exit on *scanf* returning EOF.

> I tried to increase rcx ... but then it gives a segmentation fault.

The above issue was actually a blessing because, as you reported, increasing the number of iterations was triggering 'segmentation fault'. This is due to not following the rules when invoking *realloc*. The address goes in RDI and the new total size goes in RSI; you got it reversed! Additionally, if *realloc* has to physically relocate the allocation (most of the time it doen't have to), then it will have moved the contents along with it. You don't need to do that all over, and certainly not while using the wrong registers.

### My suggestion for this part of your program

I'm building this on the premise that the dynamic adaptation of the number of elements in the array should follow the sequence 5 -> 10 -> 20 -> 40 ... and that no changes are performed unless they are strictly necessary (eg. a 6th input was received while the size of the array is still 5, or an 11th input was received while the size of the array is still 10, and so on):

```
   mov   rdi, ARRAY_SIZE
   mov   rsi, ELEMENT_SIZE
   call  calloc                 ; -> RAX
   mov   [arrayPtr], rax
   add   rax, ARRAY_SIZE * ELEMENT_SIZE
   mov   [arrayEnd], rax

   ...

   mov   rdi, [arrayPtr]
inputLoop:
   push  rdi                    ; (1)
   mov   rdi, inputPrompt
   call  printf
   mov   rdi, intFormat
   mov   rsi, intInput
   call  scanf
   pop   rdi                    ; (1)
   cmp   eax, EOF               ; Did scanf() return -1?
   je    inputDone

   cmp   rdi, [arrayEnd]
   jb    inputNotFull

   mov   rdi, [arrayPtr]
   mov   rsi, [arrayEnd]
   sub   rsi, rdi
   shl   rsi, 1                 ; Double current size
   push  rsi                    ; (2)
   call  realloc                ; -> RAX
   pop   rsi                    ; (2)
   mov   [arrayPtr], rax
   add   rax, rsi
   mov   [arrayEnd], rax
   shr   rsi, 1
   sub   rax, rsi
   mov   rdi, rax               ; Continue at midpoint

inputNotFull:
   mov   eax, [intInput]
   stosd
   jmp   inputLoop

inputDone:
```

Do notice that I introduced a new variable *arrayEnd* that holds a pointer to right behind the array, similar to how *arrayPtr* holds a pointer to the start of the array.
**Tip**: shouldn't you check whether *calloc* and *realloc* returned successfully (inspecting RAX)?